# How to convert data in a column containing string like "4:20" to a float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

In my dataframe there is a column containing values like this:

```
 PowerPlayTimeOnIce
       0:05
       0:05
       1:24
       3:29
       1:34
        0
       0:05
        0
        0
```

How do I convert these to floats?

This method didn't work:

```
df["powerPlayTimeOnIce"] = df["powerPlayTimeOnIce"].astype('float')
```

EDIT:Updated data-example to fit problem better

Comment: What does 0:05 should convert to?

Comment: 5 seconds, so its minutes:seconds

Comment: Is this a pandas question?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for being unclear about it

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel My expected results is that the time can be converted to a float so that the differences in time between observations doesn't change

Comment: @MisterButter Presumably, you want a float representing  fraction of a minute (so that `0:05` becomes `0.08333333`), but that's not the only option, which is why people are asking you to be specific.

Comment: @chepner totaly understand your questions, I came to mind to have it converted to seconds representation so that 0:05 becomes 5 and 1:00 becomes 60 and so om

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `to_datetime`

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df.PowerPlayTimeOnIce,format='%M:%S')
s.dt.minute*60+s.dt.second
Out[881]: 
0      5
1      5
2     84
3    209
4     94
5      5
Name: PowerPlayTimeOnIce, dtype: int64
```

Update

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df.PowerPlayTimeOnIce,format='%M:%S',errors='coerce')

(s.dt.minute*60+s.dt.second).fillna(0)
Out[886]: 
0      5.0
1      5.0
2     84.0
3    209.0
4     94.0
5      5.0
6      0.0
Name: PowerPlayTimeOnIce, dtype: float64
```

---

Data input

```
  PowerPlayTimeOnIce
0               0:05
1               0:05
2               1:24
3               3:29
4               1:34
5               0:05
6                  0
```

Comment: The column contains the value 0 in some rows,  which I forgot to mention. So i get error "time data 0 does not match format '%M:%S' (match)"

Comment: Thank you, believe it's gonna work, messed up my notebook so had to restart kernel. Thank you very much for the solution!

Comment: @MisterButter just let us know whether it work or not

Comment: worked excellent in the format you wrote it, but changed all "s" to "df " and the rest of the data disappears. Perhaps it is not allowed?

Comment: @MisterButter you need to assign it back rather than change it 

`df['New']=(s.dt.minute*60+s.dt.second).fillna(0)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['0:05',
        '0:05',
        '1:24',
        '3:29',
        '1:34',
        '0:05']


def convert(s):
    minutes, seconds = map(int, s.split(":"))
    return 60 * minutes + seconds


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['powerPlayTimeOnIce'])
print(df['powerPlayTimeOnIce'].apply(convert))
```

**Output**

```
0      5
1      5
2     84
3    209
4     94
5      5
Name: powerPlayTimeOnIce, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a very verbose flow and you don’t have a huge dataset. You could do:

```
df[['min', 'sec']] = df['powerPlayTimeOnIce'].str.split(':', expand=True)

df[['min'] = df[['min'].astype('int')
df['sec'] = df['sec'].apply(lambda x: float('0.'+x), axis=1)

df['diff_in_seconds'] = df['min']/60 + df['sec']
```

So I split your data to min and sec. and from there you can turn to whatever format.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, easy to follow! Looking for speed, I do not have a huge dataset(2 seasons on NHL games played), but I have shit code so it takes a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_timedelta` + the `.total_seconds()` accessor. First you need to format the strings properly (HH:mm:ss) as you cannot specify a format. Though perhaps not relevant for hockey times, this can deal with large time without much issue.

```
import pandas as pd

s = df.PowerPlayTimeOnIce.replace(':', '', regex=True).str.zfill(6)
pd.to_timedelta(s.str[0:-4]+':'+s.str[-4:-2]+':'+s.str[-2::]).dt.total_seconds()
```

#### Output:

```
0          5.0
1          5.0
2         84.0
3        209.0
4         94.0
5          5.0
6          0.0
7     446161.0
8    4046161.0
Name: PowerPlayTimeOnIce, dtype: float64
```

#### Input Data

```
  PowerPlayTimeOnIce
0               0:05
1               0:05
2               1:24
3               3:29
4               1:34
5               0:05
6                  0
7          123:56:01
8         1123:56:01
```

Comment: This a small part of a dataframe with many, columns, is it possible to save it as df[”powerPlayTimeOnIce”] instead of ”s”?

Comment: @MisterBuster yes. It was just much easier to write out `s.str` instead of that lengthy Column name every time